# Powershell script to compare date column with today's date in a CSV file and export data to a different CSV

Tags: powershell

If anyone can help me with this issue.
I have one CSV file where I want to compare the date column with today's date and if it's more than 20 days I want to export the Name Column in a different CSV.

Name           Date
Test 7/7/2015
Test 4/5/2015
Test 5/2/2015

Comment: "compare the date column" Your input sample is ambiguous. Is it `M/d/yyyy` or `d/M/yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that date format in your CSV is `d/M/yyyy` and fields are whitespace-delimited:

```
$sInFile = "C:\input.csv" # Change to your actual path
$sOutFile = "C:\output.csv" # Change to your actual path

$cInCsv = Import-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Path $sInFile
$sDateFormat = "d/M/yyyy"
$iMaxDays = 20

$oNow = Get-Date
$cOutCsv = @()
foreach ($oRow in $cInCsv) {
    $oRowDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($oRow.Date, $sDateFormat, $null)
    if ( ($oNow - $oRowDate).Days -gt $iMaxDays) { $cOutCsv += $oRow }
}
$cOutCsv | Export-Csv -Path $sOutFile -NoTypeInformation
```